# How do I show AlertDialog in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am starting to learn Flutter and am working on a Calculator app. When I want to prevent the user from some action (let's say divide by zero), I want to display a Dialog showing an error message. This requires a context, but when I pass context, this results in an error.

The examples that I have seen that do display an alert dialog all appear to be the result of a button being pressed, and this uses the context that is present when the app Widget is created. My situation is that the dialog is displayed outside the creation of the widget, and it appears that the context is not valid there.

How can I display a dialog as a result of an action taken by the user rather than the clicking a button within the Widget that has been created for the app? An example would be great.

The error that I am getting is as follows:

**I/flutter ( 6990): The getter 'modalBarrierDismissLabel' was called on null.**

While I presume from what I have read that I need to restructure the code and reposition the Alert Dialog, I have no idea how to do that. The examples that I have seen that work result from a Widget created on construction that consequently uses the context available at that point. In my case, I'm attempting to create the alert dialog as a result of an outcome from the result of what a user has done, not from the pressing of a widget button.
Some of my relevant code is as follows:

```
} else if (pendingOperator == "/") {
    if (secondValue != 0) {
      setNewValue(Decimal.parse(firstValue.toString()) /
          Decimal.parse(resultString));
    } else {
      _showAlert(context, "Divide by zero is invalid");
    }
  }



class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
Decimal firstValue;
String pendingOperator;
bool clearCurrentValue = true;
String resultString = "0";

void _showAlert(BuildContext context, String text) {
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Error"),
          content: Text(text),
        ));
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new MaterialApp(
    home: new SafeArea(
  child: new Material(
    color: Colors.black,
    child: Column(
```

Comment: you have to use the context of build(BuildContext context){} you have to pass it to your method.

Comment: Can you share the Widget which contains the button? And how did you use that Widget?

Comment: First Separate your `MaterialApp` context from the `SafeArea` Context then run the code. You need to create Another class in which you need to define `SafeArea` Context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The need to show the alert is indirectly the result of a button being pressed. When that button is created, pass the context to the function that is called and use that context in the call to _showAlert.